# Box2D world.step() delay at first 2 runs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, game-engine, game-physics

I'm programming a game using ActionScript 3.0 and included Box2D classes for its physics. It's a maze/labyrinth game having a lot of walls and a ball inside.

In my main fla when I call the maze.create(), the maze is created (visually and physically) and it will dispatch an event so I know when it's done working and then I call my frameHandler which calls another function from my maze class every frame and the big delay accrues exactly at world.step() in it. BUT THE THING IS that it lags only the first two times this function runs!!!

- The reason I notice this lag, is that I've got another object starting to move according to mouse position in the same frame handler.
- The reason I'm sure the world.step() is causing it, is that everything works fine when I dont call it.

I've seen many codes using Box2d, some had more objects than i have and I know that I've created my b2World and all the objects correctly, similar to all the Box2d tutorials and stuff BUT THEY DONT LAG AT ALL. Its just mine lagging and all!!

Do you have any Idea or similar experience?
Do you have any suggestion in general how to deal with heavy functions?
PLEEEEASE +.-

Comment: Do you have a b2DebugDraw? Post some relevant code! Are there any overlapping bodies right after their creation? Post some relevant code! Are your timesteps calculated right? Post some relevant code! And last but not least: Post some code!

Comment: do you multiply your world timestep with delta time? If so, delta time is probably large in the first 1-2 frames due to resource loading.

Comment: #Philipp I dont have overlapped bodies. I've used the debugdraw before to make sure everything is placed right and it is! TimeSteps are fine (0.33, 5, 5). Dear, i didnt post the code coz i thaught u'd need my explanation anyway but ill send some as i get home.

Comment: #LearnCocos2D i dont know what is delta time. All I do is world.step(.33,5,5).

Answer (score 0):

A maze will have a lot of fixtures in close proximity making a very dense dynamic tree (the method Box2D uses to optimize collision checks). There is unlikely to be any way around this. Perhaps you could just call Step a few times after adding the static walls, but before you add the dynamic ball bodies, and consider it part of the loading process. At least the lagging movements will not be visible to the player.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately you answer is the most logical to my problem:) I actually came up with the same solution. And It works fine with hiding the lags from the player.

Comment: You know, a real loader (not just a fake loading screen) loads bites of data and the player can see the progress. But what if its all about running a function which consumes time to be done and instead of a lag (freezing game) I want it to be progressed finely in a way that does not cause any lag?!!!! What a question! But I cant explain it better!

Comment: And I have another question, this one is even more abnormal:p
I usually come up and used to come up with nice ideas for games. So I always had this serious decision for programming them for ios and then publishing "when I can afford buying a mac and an iphone"!! But after 3 years still cannot afford it and therefore cannot test or publish them for ios devices. Do you have any suggestion for a person like me with a lot of stacked codes not yet published? This dream seems to never come true!